# Wordpress how to display ACF fields in a Dynamic Table

Tags: php, html, wordpress, html-table, advanced-custom-fields

I would have to display the corresponding fields in a table that I previously created with acf. I use the page id as a guide. the first page works, the additional id is not loaded as "tr".

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

```php
elseif ( is_page(59) && have_posts() ) : // Produktübersicht
  echo '<div class="container produktuebersicht">';
      while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
          echo '<div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="inner">';
                  $parent = $post->post_parent;
                  $currentpage = $post->ID;
                  the_content(); 

                  echo '<ul class="submenu">';
                      wp_list_pages( array(
                          'depth'       => 2,
                          'child_of'    => $parent,
                          'exclude'     => '44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 57, 59',
                          'link_before' => '',
                          'title_li'    => '',
                          'sort_column' => 'menu_order'
                      ) );
                  echo '</ul> ';
                  wp_reset_postdata();  
          ?>

          <?php if(have_rows('attribute', '149', '151')): ?>
              <table class="produkttabelle">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Produktname</th>
                          <th>Wirkstoff</th>
                          <th>Darreichungsform</th>
                          <th>Status</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <?php while( have_rows('attribute', '149', '151')) : the_row(); ?>
                      <tr>
                          <td><?=$produktname = get_sub_field('produktname');?></td>
                          <td><?=$wirkstoff = get_sub_field('wirkstoff');?></td>
                          <td><?=$darreichungsform = get_sub_field('darreichungsform');?></td>
                          <td><?=$status = get_sub_field('status');?></td>
                      </tr>
                  <?php endwhile; ?>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          <?php endif; 
          echo '</div>
          </div>
      </div>'; ?>
  <?php endwhile;
```

Here's the WordPress result:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, It is important to describe your question as good as possible. To improve your chances of getting an answer, you should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

There are only two parameters to have_rows: the field_name and the post_ID (defaults to the current post)

You can put your posts id's in an array and use foreach to go through each one

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Like this?
...
$post_id = array( 'post__in' => array(149,151) );
...
<?php if(have_rows('attribute', $post_id)): ?>
...
<?php while( have_rows('attribute', $post_id)) : the_row(); ?>

Comment: $post_ids = array(149,151);
foreach($post_ids as $p_id){
   if(have_rows('attribute', $p_id)){
       ........
   }
}